# Is header redirection injectable

Tags: php, header, code-injection

Its all begin with the a redirect function I have used to enable language switching. I use `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` to redirect user back to his previous page which is redirected through javascript `window.location.href` .

I've tried

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=');';
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

and it redirected to an error page `http://localhost/);`

However I know that there might be some trick to make it a leakage, therefore I'm asking is there any injection method to this? I won't mind to let user modify their http_referer and send to an error page if the code is not vulnerable.

---

update

What I'm worry of is if user can do something like

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=')';
$mysqli->query($query);
header('Location: http://localhost ');
```

similar to

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=");$mysqli->query($query);header('Location: http://localhost ');";`
Its not executable in my previous code however who know if it is actually vulnarable.

Comment: Err, yes, anybody can send you whatever referrer they want. It's a completely user-supplied field.

Comment: Mom, is that you? Jeez, we talked about this.... Don't user Referrer header.

Comment: If you're referring to SQL injection, this case isn't very similar.  With SQL injection, a malicious user can execute code of their choice on their database.  In this situation... the user can control which page they're redirected to, which isn't really a security issue.

Comment: I know to avoid referrer header however my question is `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` vulnerable to injection? I've tried to avoid http_referer however I have no idea how to safely redirect user back to their current page using javascript( which is a client-side )

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: That would only be possible if you where using eval

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be anything supplied by input (e.g. modify by a cURL call, or modify by a browser plugin/add-on/extension, etc).

Therefore, you shouldn't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to do important task such as page flow like you did.

In [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), it said:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: you can see that I know that it can be modified. To redirect user to the previous page I think it should be using something similar to http_referer so somehow still editable, so why not you show some better substitution?

Comment: You can setup a list of valid values & more importantly a default value. All other values outside the list should fall back to default value.